# Find the occurence from the list of strings in the dataset

Tags: python, dataset

I have a list

```
top = ['GME', 'MVIS', 'TSLA', 'AMC']
```

And I have a dataset

```
dt | text
2021-03-19 20:59:49+06 | I only need GME to hit 20 eod to make up
2021-03-19 20:59:51+06 | lads why is my account covered in more red
2021-05-21 15:54:27+06 | Oh my god, we might have 2 green days in a row
2021-05-21 15:56:06+06 | Why are people so hype about a 4% TSLA move
```

So I want to get all the occurrences from the list of words in the dataset
My output needs to look like this

```
dt | text
2021-03-19 20:59:49+06 | I only need GME to hit 20 eod to make up
2021-05-21 15:56:06+06 | Why are people so hype about a 4% TSLA move
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the dataframe by searching each tag in the text of each row.
A customized function could solve this:

```
df[df['text'].map(lambda txt: any(tag in txt for tag in top))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
import re
import pandas as pd
top = ['GME', 'MVIS', 'TSLA', 'AMC']
df = pd.DataFrame({"text":["I only need GME to hit 20 eod to make up","lads why is my account covered in more red","Oh my god, we might have 2 green days in a row","Why are people so hype about a 4% TSLA move"]})
out_df = df[df["text"].str.contains("|".join(re.escape(i) for i in top))]
print(out_df)
```

output

```
                                          text
0     I only need GME to hit 20 eod to make up
3  Why are people so hype about a 4% TSLA move
```

Explanation: [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) by default treat what it gets as regex, I used `|` to build regular expression which says `GME` or `MVIS` or `TSLA` or `AMC` (`GME|MVIS|TSLA|AMC`). I used `re.escape` which is not required in this particular case, but is useful to prevent unexpected behavior in case any word in list contain special character (enumerated in [Regular Expression Syntax chapter of re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)).